# Is it safe to delete /root/sent in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mutt

I have a server running ubuntu 14.04
What is inside of /root/sent? 
It is currently taking of 34GB of my server space. 
It is safe to delete it?

Comment: This question is probably best for the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange website.

Comment: How is this a programming question? You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. The [help] has details regarding the types of question that are on-topic here if you need more info.

Comment: I forgot that Ask Ubuntu was part of Stack Exchange. That would be the best place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

This folder would typically contain the contents (or some of the contents) of emails that you have sent using the server. As to whether or not it's safe to delete, that question is determined by whether or not you need those files. If you don't need the records or the files, then probably, yes.